# Adding an icon in an exe through py2exe

Tags: python-2.7, icons, py2exe

I am making an exe through py2exe using a python script.
I had already gone through many examples of setup.py but none is working. I am using windows 7 64 bit and python 2.7.

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
import time
setup( 
windows = [ 
{ 
"script": "myapp.py", 
"icon_resources": [(1, "Windows.ico")] 
} 
], 
)
time.sleep(2)
```

But dist produced through this setup.py contains myapp.exe with default exe image, **not the icon I included**. In cmd I am using **python stup.py py2exe**

Answer (score 0):

I use py2exe through gui2exe and never had a problem with icon.

With gui2exe, you don't have to write setup.py and works great with py2exe, cx_freeze, etc.

You can get it here http://code.google.com/p/gui2exe/
And just start gui2exe.py by double clicking it (no installation required).